# How to understand the path in DLE?

Tags: php, datalife-engine

I would like to know how works the path in DataLife Engine

`<source src="[xfvalue_videopath]" type="video/mp4"> </video>';`

i have a slider with 4 videos, and this path direct this videos on slider, how can i change the path?

```
videopath|video path (dont touch!)|97|text||1|0|0|0
videopathimage|video preview (dont touch!)|97|text||1|0|0|0
```

this is located in xfields.txt, as I understand this is the path

Answer (score 0):

In admin panel, from **additional fields** section ( of news ), you can change the xfields:

[image: DLE Admin Panel]